# How to form parameter expression string to always default to current year

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssas

I have an expression string that is pulling in the year from SSAS using a dimension for year and calendar month. I want to modify this so that it automatically defaults to the current year.

[image]

[image]

```
[Allegation Closed Date].[Year].&[2013]
```

A harder example of this but pretty much the same thing, is where I want to default to current year but use a pre-set month. In the example below it  would always be the 1st month of the current year but can be set to any month. The problem I am having is that I cant just default to a current year because this information is being pulled from a table field.

`[Allegation Closed Date].[Calendar Month].&[2013-01]`

I was thinking I could just do something like this and it would work:

`[Allegation Closed Date].[Year].&[Year(Now())]`

I tried a couple different variations on the string above and none of them worked. I have also tried creating a calculated field in the dataset called currentyear and then calling this field with:

`[Allegation Closed Date].[Year].&[CurrentYear]`

Tried the method below and that did not work so I thought I could redesign the query to filter out all years greater than current year. Here is a screenshot of the query designer.

[image]

The query is a little hard to read, it is:

`WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Allegation Closed Date].[Year].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Allegation Closed Date].[Year].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Allegation Closed Date].[Year].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL SELECT {[Measures].[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue], [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS , [Allegation Closed Date].[Year].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Allegation Status].[Allegation Status].&[Closed] } ) ON COLUMNS FROM [Allegation Analysis])`

So I figured out what to enter so it would default to current year and it is:

```
="[Allegation Closed Date].[Year].&["+CSTR(Year(Today))+"]"
```

Still have to figure out what to enter for month but at least I know I am on the right track.

Any help is greatly appreciated still on how to format to be year-month.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify an expression, then it needs to be a VB.NET expression, not MDX.

```
=Now.Year
```

will always return the current year.

If you want to use an MDX expression, then you will need to set up a dataset that executes that MDX as its query, and then set the parameter to "Get values from a query" and select the new dataset.

Comment: So I could do something like [Allegation Closed Date].[Year].&[=Now.Year]?

Comment: You can filter the final dataset either at the SSRS level (look at the dataset properties in SSRS to see filters. or use the parameter in Anlaysis Services query: http://www.tictacti.com/DevBlog/post/2010/06/24/SSAS-Reports-in-Reporting-Services.aspx  (I'm not too familiar with a parameter in an SSAS query, so I can't vouch for the details of that.)